# Save Keras model for production mode without TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to save a trained Keras model, so that it can be used in the Django [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) backend of an application. I did a lot of research, but it seems there isn't any way to use these models without TensorFlow installed.

So, what is the use of this storage? I don't want to install a heavy library like TensorFlow on the server. I tested saving with [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) and joblib, as well as Keras' own *model.save()*.

Is there a way to load this model without installing TensorFlow and only with Keras itself?

This is a part of my code,

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout

xtrain, ytrain = np.array(xtrain), np.array(ytrain)
ytrain = np.reshape(ytrain, (ytrain.shape[0], 1, 1))
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(150, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(xtrain.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(LSTM(150, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(25))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(xtrain, ytrain, batch_size=1, epochs=7)
model.save('model.h5')
```

which normally works perfectly, but if I use the model elsewhere, I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Comment: Keras depends on tensorflow, so the answer is probably no.

Comment: Does the current answer have any merit? Or is it completely bogus? (Not rhetorical questions.)

Answer (score -5):

You do not need to use TensorFlow in production. You can use coefficient by replacing what random functions in your programming language.

Sample: Input array, time coefficients matrixes, and unboxed system inputs to output with feedback system in the box containers.

```
temp = tf.random.normal([10], 1, 0.2, tf.float32)
temp = np.asarray(temp) * np.asarray([ coefficient_0, coefficient_1, coefficient_2, coefficient_3, coefficient_4, coefficient_5, coefficient_6, coefficient_7, coefficient_8, coefficient_9 ]) #action = actions['up']
temp = tf.nn.softmax(temp)

action = int(np.argmin(temp))
```

Comment: "Is there a way to load this model without installing tensorflow and only with keras itself?" Where are you loading the model?

Comment: And also the code does use tensorflow, which is the opposite of what the question asked.

Comment: As an example we do not need Tensorflow to run output parameters from the Tensorflow training.

Comment: Your code literally says `tf.random.normal` at the top. In what way is that not using Tensorflow?

Comment: This is referenced in [a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421793/is-the-re-use-of-the-image-on-these-posts-appropriate).